# Why is my site not showing up on Google?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My site has been live since July this year but is still not showing up on Google.

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check your robots.txt file, if you found code like below mention:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Then right this code like below mention:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Or

Might be this meta code is available on you website: `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

so here replace "noindex" with "index"

I hope you might be get solution from above suggestion, or you can share your website so i can analyses much better and give proper solution.